# Change Default Colors Of Morris.js Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, morris.js

I've just started working with the Morris.js bar chart source and am having a small issue trying to get the bars to have different colors for the two different Y keys. But for some reason the results I'm getting is it it's only setting the one color it's not running the else.

```
<script>
    new Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar-chart',
        data: [
            { day: 'Day 1', amount1: 1, amount2: 1 },
            { day: 'Day 2', amount1: 2, amount2: 1 },
            { day: 'Day 3', amount1: 3, amount2: 2 },
            { day: 'Day 4', amount1: 4, amount2: 2 },
            { day: 'Day 5', amount1: 5, amount2: 3 },
            { day: 'Day 6', amount1: 6, amount2: 3 },
            { day: 'Day 7', amount1: 7, amount2: 4 }
        ],
        xkey: 'day',
        ykeys: ['amount1', 'amount2'],
        labels: ['Amount One', 'Amount Two'],

        hideHover: 'auto',

        barColors: function(row,series,type){
            if(row.ykeys=='amount1'){
                return "#9b5cd4";
            } 
            else {
                return "#5e2590";
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to use a function for this, in my opinion you can just set the option **barColors** with a simple array like this:

```
barColors:['#9b5cd4', '#5e2590'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with the following assumptions:

-*that 'row' argument your barColors function receives is the array which contains the values you have in the **ykeys** attribute up there*. Those are ['amount1', 'amount2'];

-there is *nothing in the barColors function that references a specific position of your ykeys array* so your if condition is always comparing an array to a string and it is **always false**.

If my assumptions are valid, once your function reads **row.ykeys** values it sees **['amount1', 'amount2']**; then it proceeds to the the if statement which goes: *is ['amount1', 'amount2'] equal to 'amount1'*?  And then tt returns false and so it goes into the else block and returns '#5e2590'.

Just a little logic glitch there. Try to specify which one of the values inside of row.ykeys you're trying to compare with.

By the way, I wrote without having any specific Morris.js knowledge, so if there is any magic Morris.js does that would make that if inside the barColors function work without having to access array elements or iterate over the array, then that is unknown to me.

Try to inspect the variables and attributes using chrome dev tools, or use console.log to see what values your code is getting. This will help you get unblocked when problems like this one block you.